# Unloading COM Objects C#

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly clean up Excel interop objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c)

I am using EXCEL INTEROP for reading excel files in my .NET application. However I see that after am done with it, I still see the EXCEL.EXE in Windows Task Manager.

The code is as follows:

```
ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
Workbooks workBooks = excel.Workbooks;
Workbook workBook = workBooks.Open(fileName,0,true,5,"","",true,XLPlatform.xlWindows,"\t",false,false,0,true,1,0);


foreach (Name name in workBook.Names)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // =#REF!#REF! indicates that the named range refers to nothing. Ignore these..
                        if (name.Value != "=#REF!#REF!")
                        {
                            if (!retNamedRanges.ContainsKey(name.Name))
                            {
                                string keyName = name.Name;
                                object value = name.RefersToRange.get_Value(missing);
                                retNamedRanges.Add(keyName, value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }



if(workBook!=null)
{
    workBook.Close(false,missing,missing);
}
if(workBook!=null)
{
    workBooks.Close();
}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBooks);
workBook = null;
workBooks = null;
excel.Application.Quit();
excel.Quit();
excel = null;
```

I have tried to do all possible things to clean up, but still it does not go. There are multiple EXCEL files that I need to read. Typically after my application executes I see multiple instances of EXCEL.EXE.

Is there anything else am missing with the clean up?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hey alex. I went through it yesterday and tried the above code. It did not help!!!

Answer (score 0):

*"Some process specific to my application I am doing..."*

Actually, this is most likely where the problem lies. As in the referenced duplicate, if you reference a property of the `ApplicationClass` then you'll need to make sure you dereference that property before the garbage collector will tidy up and remove Excel.

So, for instance, copy any data you need to `string`, `int`, etc. (or your own internal types based on these base types).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I just added the some process specific thing am doing to the code above. It is reading all the named ranges and storing it into a Dictionary<string,object> which I am using for other purposes in other part of the code

Comment: I've a feeling that the "object" references are storing references to things inside your spreadsheet - so a reference to the source Excel spreadsheet is retained in memory. Instead, create strings (or ints) and store those instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Marshal.**Final**ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) instead of ReleaseComObject.
Also call it on your "ApplicationClass excel" instance.